# MediaElement flash fallback getting called twice

Tags: html, html5-video, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I have integrated the medialement player. It works great on all browsers except firefox. As I am trying to integrate a mp4 video. I know that firefox does not support mp4, and hence setup a flash fallback. The flash fallback works, but it gets called twice. And I have 2 instances of the player getting played simultaneously. Any idea why would this happen?

The code:

```
<video id="player1" width="700" height="430">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="'+videoUrl+'" />
  <object width="700" height="430" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="/assets/flashmediaelement.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file="'+videoUrl+'" />
  </object>
</video>
```

The **videoUrl** is submitted by the user. The user is given a prompt to paste the URL.